# How to insert function into data structure?

Tags: c++, function, data-structures

In a data-structure, how do you insert a function?

```
struct Student_info {
std::string name;
double midterm, final;
unsigned int& counter;
std::vector<double> homework;
double overall = grade(students[counter]);
};
```

always get this type of error:-

a. "variable" was not declared in this code.

b. "Student_info::counter" cannot appear in a constant-expression.

c. an array reference cannot appear in a constant-expression.

d. a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression

edit:-
oopps, i mean student_info contain in a vector, wait, why that's info needed anyway... Dx

oh, and btw, this is from Accelerated C++, a book obviously, and I'm trying to answer one of its exercise, then I need to know this part, not found any on  the book Dx

the question is 4-6. Rewrite the Student_info structure to calculate the grades immediately and store only the final grade.

Comment: "Student_info is a vector". No it's not. It's a `struct`.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific about what you are trying to do here.  double overall = grade(students[counter]);
 looks very wrong, shouldnt you be doing something like void set_grade(){ overall = students[counter]; }

Comment: @Vastor I think you need to take a look at a C++ book to get the concepts, then return and ask here.

Comment: lol, in another question posted, I explain too much on what to do, and the question got closed, and told to narrow the question... Dx

Comment: I think the other question was closed as it was not a real queston just a mess of information. This is different in that you are obviously coming from a less strict language and have not yet grokked the fundamental syntax of C++. This makes it hard to understand your question as you are mixing the syntax of your original language and C++ in such a way that it makes the question nearly imposable to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **NOT** dynamically insert a function into a structure.

You can declare a structure that has a method()

```
struct Student_info
{
    void doDomethingToStudent()
    {
         // Manipulate the object here.
    }
    // STUFF
};
```

Also you can not initialize member like above.

```
double overall = grade(students[counter]);
```

Here you need to create constructor that will initialize members.

```
struct Student_info
{
    Student_info(std::string& studentName, unsigned int& externalCounter)
        : name(studentName)
        , midterm(0)
        , final(0)
        , counter(externalCounter)
        , homework()

        // It is not clear if overall is a normal memeber
        // Or a static member of the class
        , overall(grade(students[counter]))
    {}
    // STUFF
};
int main()
{
    unsigned int counter   = 0;
    Student_info bob("Bob", counter);
}
```

Comment: good, the first answer is what I'm searching for, also, how about if I'm not learned constructor yet? are there any alternative?

Comment: Constructors/Destructor are nearly always in the same chapter as your first first introduction to a class (A class is the same as a structure) they are that fundamental. Go back and read chapter 1/2

Comment: wait, did we are talking about a same book? I'm lost about what are you talking about :s

Comment: @Vastor: If your book does not talk of constructor/destructor in first 1/2 chapters then you should better throw it away. Pick up one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: well, Accelerated C++ is one of the book, which I have, and If never read it, unlike other C++ book/tutorial, which define each tools, but teach how to use it (like in art/drawing class, rather than teach to know each color, the book teach oh how to use it instead(color theory etc)), btw, I use learncpp.com to know each tools in c++(thought some claim that it contain nothing about vector(luckily Accelerated C++ has it on chapter 3))

Comment: btw, I'm beginner's that start programming with C++, which the person in your given link claim the book has steep learning curve, well he's right, I need to read twice each chapter, yet, still misinformed on some part.

Comment: oh, and btw, thnx for your link, I think I'm gonna get the other book too, like C++ FAQ.. and maybe drop the leanrcpp.com.. =S